# GNU Make: customize library search path in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, static-libraries, gnu-make

Currently to include a custom static library in my project repo I need to tell the compiler the full path of the library, like

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ ../lib/libnt.a $(LDFLAGS)
```

but I actually want to add a custom search path so that I can write

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lnt $(LDFLAGS)
```

instead. Is that possible? I tried to specify `PATH` environment variable but that won't work.

Comment: Use the `-L` (note capitalized) to specify a directory to search for libraries.  You can give `-L` more than one time to search multiple directories.  They'll be searched in the order they're given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PATH` environment var is for the shell, I don't see why you even assumed it would work. Use the `-L` linker flag instead:

```
LDFLAGS = ... stuff you put here ... -L/search/path/for/custom/libs
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                     This part
```

Comment: It's not that `PATH` is for the shell.  It's that `PATH` is used to find executables that can be run as commands, either from the shell or from other executables or scripts (Python, Perl, etc. all use `PATH` as well when trying to run programs).  But, `PATH` is never used to find things that are _not_ programs, and that includes libraries.

Comment: My bad. I should have read the linker options documentation carefully.

Comment: @KevinSayHi You're welcome. Yap, google a bit around for "using GCC" et al. It'll surely be helpful (that's how I learned using it). What's best is most of the flags apply to `clang` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple make var defintion.

```
LIBLDIR =   ../lib/
#
#
#
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^  -L$(LIBLDIR) -lnt $(LDFLAGS)
```